# jQuery validation custom messages with field name

Tags: javascript, jquery, localization, jquery-validate

I'm trying to find a way to have option to switch between two languages, and therefore I need store some custom messages in the `messages_en.js` file.

Is it possible to store custom messages in messages_en.js for example:

```
name: {
   required: 'Enter name',
   minlength: 'Name should consist of min. {0} characters',
   maxlength: 'Name is too long',
}
```

or

```
name: $.validator.format( "{0} should consist of min. {1} characters" ),
```

where `{0}` is field name?

`messages_en.js`

```
$.extend( $.validator.messages, {
  required: "This field is required.",
  remote: "Please fix this field.",
  email: "Please enter a valid email address.",
  url: "Please enter a valid URL.",
  date: "Please enter a valid date.",
  dateISO: "Please enter a valid date (ISO).",
  number: "Please enter a valid number.",
  digits: "Please enter only digits.",
  equalTo: "Please enter the same value again.",
  maxlength: $.validator.format( "Please enter no more than {0} characters." ),
  minlength: $.validator.format( "Please enter at least {0} characters." ),
  rangelength: $.validator.format( "Please enter a value between {0} and {1} characters long." ),
  range: $.validator.format( "Please enter a value between {0} and {1}." ),
  max: $.validator.format( "Please enter a value less than or equal to {0}." ),
  min: $.validator.format( "Please enter a value greater than or equal to {0}." ),
  step: $.validator.format( "Please enter a multiple of {0}." )
} );
```

Comment: Please look at the duplicates linked above.  The `{0}` placeholder is used within.

Answer (score 5):

You can pass a function as the message value like as below :

```
$.validator.messages.required = function (param, inputField) {
    return 'Please enter ' + inputField.name;
}
```

Here is Demo : [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/acm5fmks/)

Comment: This is really a good solution, only if I can set the required message individually to one field. Now the message will be applied to all fields.

Comment: That's great it helped you too. @neuroine you can up vote.